# Specify a form field as not required at instance creation

Tags: django, django-forms

In Django I have a ModelForm that is used to create an object, however I would also like to use this same form to enable users to create a template for that object in order to save the users time from repeatedly filling out the fields.

I still would like to use some of the validation of the form (ie: is this field in correct date format) but remove the required part of it since when creating a template none of the fields would be required. Is there a way to set certain field's to Required=False when creating an instance of the form so that when they are creating an object the fields are required but when they are creating a template the fields are still validated by the same standards when input but are not required.

Small Example

```
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=False)



class PersonForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Person


normal_instance = PersonForm()
template_instance = PersonForm()
```

So in this example, in the normal_instance I would like to still get a validation error if the field is blank or exceeds the max_length but in the template_instance I would only like to get a validation error if the field exceeds the max_length. Is there a way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can control these attributes at the time of initialization in the form's `__init__`

```
from django import forms
class PersonForm(forms.Form):
    some_field=forms.CharField(max_length=20)

    def __init__(self, *args,**kwargs):
        required = kwargs.get('required', True)
        super(PersonForm,self).__init__(*args,**kwargs)
        self.fields['some_field'].required = required
```

and in `template_instance`

```
template_instance = PersonForm(required=False)
```

You can leave `normal_instance = PersonForm()` alone, as it is set to `required=True`  by default